# check if dictionary value (list) already exists and update

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `dict[str,list[MyClass]]` in my class. I need to define a method `addElement`. I would like it to add a new key-value pair (with an empty list) if the key doesn't exist, and otherwise put the specified `c` value into the existing list.

Now, when I print the result I have all the keys needed so this part works fine. The problem is that every `list` has only 1 element inside. I checked the result with some `print` and I found out that my code never enters in the `if` statement it just jumps to `else`. I think I did all checks needed so something is missing...

This is the code :

```
class MyDict:
    items:dict[str,list[MyClass]]={}

    # other stuff omitted

    def addElement(self, p: str, c: MyClass):
        tmp: list[MyClass] = self.items.get(p)
        if(tmp == None or len(tmp) == 0):
            print("key not exists, inserting")
            self.items.update({p : [c]})
        else:
            print("existing key, adding")
            self.items.update({p : [c]+tmp})
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: As an aside, you do understand that `items` as described here belongs to *the class itself*, and **not** to individual instances, yes? Anyway, if the linked duplicates don't help, then the problem is somewhere else - for example, the `p` values that you expect to match don't actually match, or something like that. You would need to ask again, making sure that you have a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes I DO understand that it belongs to the class itself.  There is also a constructor but I didn't wrote it. If you asked me before closing the question I could add some code. Maybe I'm missing your suggestion, can you be more explicit?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ok thanks I will create a better question then. By the way I think the problem is that I created the dictionary using {} while I should use "defaultDic" I will check

Comment: See the linked duplicates. You asked how to make a dictionary with values that are lists, such that a new list is created when necessary, and appended to otherwise. The linked duplicates suggest various approaches for this problem. The code you have written is too much work for the problem, but I can't directly see how it would cause a failure - not without 1) enough code that someone else can copy and paste; 2) an exact sequence of input that causes the problem; 3) an exact description of what happens, what is supposed to happen instead, and how that is different.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel mh ok I will be more careful next time thanks